# Type for an item in React component map

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I spent some time on searching an answer on stackoverflow and haven't found something so far, so I decided to ask. I currently have a map with 2 items (Tables) potentially it can be more, where a single key is a name of react component and a value is component itself. These components are tables (`Owners` & `Overview`), they get `data` as a `prop`, prepare rows and heads out of it and then pass them to another common react component (`Table`). I display table one at a time, choosing it via tabs & dropdown list. Type of data can be different and depends on what I get from back end.

Interfaces:

```
export interface ITables {
    owners: IOwnersTable,
    overview: IOverviewTable,
    [key: string]: ITables[keyof ITables]
}

interface IOverviewTable extends ITable {
    data: OverviewData,
}

interface IOwnersTable extends ITable {
    data: OwnersData,
}

interface ITable {
    isLoading: boolean
    // some other items
}

export type TTableComponent = React.FC<TOwnersTable> | React.FC<TOverviewTable>;
```

Map itself:

```
export const tableComponentMap: ITables = {
    'owners': OwnersTable,
    'overview': OverviewTable
};
```

Get and render a table depends on selected `tableName`:

```
const TableComponent: TTableComponent = tableComponentMap[tableName];

return (
    <TableComponent
        data={data}
        isLoading={isLoading}
    />
)
```

One of the table components (second the same but data is different):

```
const OwnersTable: React.FC<IOwnersTable> = ({data, ...rest}) => {
// prepare heads and rows logic out of data

  return (
    <Table
        head={head}
        rows={rows}
        {...rest}
    />
  )
};

export default OwnersTable;
```

**Question**: what is a type of a variable for the map component should be to prevent conflicts of different `data` types? Is it actually possible to type it at all? Currently I am getting next type error for the line `data={data}`:

> Error:(66, 25) TS2322: Type 'IOwnersTable' is not assignable to type 'IOverviewTable'.
>     Type 'IOwnersTable' is missing the following properties from type 'IOverviewTable': ...

**Note**: Please do not suggest use type `any` or disable check for `any` in tsconfig.

**Note**: I used an union operation, but it seems not a proper way to handle my case.

- Typescript v.3.5.1
- React v.16.8.6

Comment: How does the error continue, what properties is it missing?

Comment: Basically all from data of IOverviewTable, for example OwnerData has id, owners, entriesNumber, dependencies and some others, OverviewData has id, pages, artefacts, regulation.

Comment: what exactly is the type of `TableComponent` now? what's the context of that ts error? current description seems insufficient.

Comment: @hackape thx for pointed that out I was debugging code and missed this type. I edited my question. Basically it's an union operation, however, I found that union is not proper way to handle things in this case

Comment: Can you provide a [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2) link demonstrating your issue please?